# Removing references to source workbook in copied sheet

Tags: excel, vba, reference, copy, worksheet

I have a macro for routinely copying multiple worksheets from a workbook each to a new workbook for remote editing. Copying a worksheet to a new workbook creates links back to the worksheet in the original workbook. I can remove the links from formulas, but I cannot find a way to remove the links from named ranges using VBA (obviously, I do not want to do this manually through the Names Manager!).

I have seen descriptions using `ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add`, but this means I then have to also add each range. I've also tried `ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink` and `ActiveWorkbook.Connections` without success. Is there no way to edit the strings to get rid of the the link itself? Preferably with a wildcard. E.g. to change `"[2020 2021 activities planner.xlsm]Lists'!*"` to `"Lists!*"` Without having to change the cell references e.g. `$A$2:$A$58`

My code so far:

```
Sub Save_NPO_XLSX()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim Path As String
Dim Folder As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim delLinks As Variant
'
Path = "N:\ABC\DEF\GHI\Monthly plans\"
Folder = Path '& "\" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & "\"
If Dir(Folder, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir Folder

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Call Unprotect_AllSheets

        For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

            If sh.Name = "Angie" Or sh.Name = "Brad" _
            Or sh.Name = "Hugo" Or sh.Name = "Kathie" Or sh.Name = "Sally" _
            Then

                Set wb = Workbooks.Add

                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Instructions").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
                    Cells.Replace What:="=[wb]", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False

                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lists").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
                    Cells.Replace What:="=[wb]", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False

                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tasks").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
                    Cells.Replace What:="=[wb]", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False

                sh.Activate
                If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
                    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
                End If
                ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=wb.Sheets("Lists")
                    Cells.Replace What:="=[wb]", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False

                wb.SaveAs Filename:=Folder & ActiveSheet.Name & "_Planner_" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD")

                wb.Activate

                delLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)

                wb.BreakLink _
                Name:=delLinks(1), _
                Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks

                wb.Save

            wb.Close
            End If
        Next

    Call LockCols

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered pasting values only?

Comment: Thanks @SJR - unfortunately `Sheets.Copy` does not support `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`. But I think I have not been able to see the forest for the trees - the `Sheets.Copy` approach is wrong and I should be using `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveSheet.Name` instead and then deleting unwanted sheets.